# Change amount of lines and dots in native captcha in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, captcha

I know how to change density and number of lines and dots in **`native captcha`** in **`magento 1.x`**, but I am not able to find how to change it in **`magento 2.x`**.

Can anyone suggest a way to change number of lines and dots for native captcha in **`magento 2.x`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the path of file in which values of number of lines and number of dots can be changed in magento 2.x.

Path is:
**`/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php`**

Variables which are responsible for frequency of dots and lines are:

```
protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 100;
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 5;
```

Thanks for taking interest in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using magento 2.3.3 or above then there is no directory for captcha Image generation in this path : **/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha**

For 2.3.3 or above Magento moved captcha generation code in **/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/**, so you need to override **\Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel** that extends **\Zend\Captcha\Image.php** like below :

First you need to add a preference in your custom module's di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel" type="Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultModel"/>
```

with below code:

```
class DefaultModel extends \Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel 
{
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
    \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData,
    \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory,
    $formId
  ) 
  {
    parent::__construct($session,$captchaData,$resLogFactory,$formId);
    $this->setDotNoiseLevel(0);
    $this->setLineNoiseLevel(0); 
  } 
}
```

you can set any value in these **setDotNoiseLevel** & **setLineNoiseLevel** as per your requirement. Let me know if you still face the issue.