# Override captcha library class in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, captcha

With reference to my own [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128141/change-amount-of-lines-and-dots-in-native-captcha-in-magento-2-x), I have found that we can change density and number of lines and dots in native magento 2 captcha in **`/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php`**.

Now my question is that how can we override above file class using custom module, because we don't want to make changes directly in core magento files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not so complicated. First in `composer.json` file add this line in `psr-0` node

```
"Zend_Captcha": "app/code/"
```

so it will look like that

```
"psr-0": {
   "": "app/code/",
   "Zend_Captcha": "app/code/"
},
```

Then create directory `app/code/Zend/Captcha/` and place there your file `Image.php` that you want to override.

After that just run `composer update`.

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: If my module does not have composer.json, then is it possible?

Comment: Yes. But this change has to be done in main composer.json file of magento 2

Comment: But I am afraid that this file would be updated when I will upgrade magento to next version.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nope. This file is not changed during magento update. To update magento you have to change this file but it is not changed automatically.

Comment: Sorry, your solution did not work for me.

Comment: How you were testing?  I have created file called `test.php` with this content `<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$image = new Zend_Captcha_Image();
echo $image->getWidth();` and override getWidth() function to return always 100 for example

Comment: I want to set value of $_dotNoiseLevel and $_lineNoiseLevel from custom module. How can I set it?

Comment: did you run `composer update`? could you paste content of file `vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php`

Comment: After using **`composer update`**, it worked. If I want to use it as personal extension, how can I include my **composer.json** in it?

Comment: Is there any solution for that? It was much easy in Magento 1.x.

Comment: How to override vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/pa.xml, Could you please let me know?

Comment: Instead of changing in Magento default `composer.json` can we also overwrite that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using magento 2.3.3 or above then there is no directory for captcha Image generation in this path : /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha

For 2.3.3 or above Magento moved captcha generated code in /vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/, so you need to override \Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel that extends \Zend\Captcha\Image like below :

First, you need to add a preference in your custom module's di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel" type="Custom\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel"/>
```

with below code:

```
class DefaultModel extends \Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel 
{


  public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
    \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData,
    \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory,
    $formId
) 
{

    parent::__construct($session,$captchaData,$resLogFactory,$formId);
    $this->setDotNoiseLevel(0);
    $this->setLineNoiseLevel(0); 
} 
}
```

you can set setDotNoiseLevel & setLineNoiseLevel as per your requirement. 
Let me know if you still face the issue.