# Magento 2: How to override Zend library files function only?

Tags: magento2, overrides, custom, zend-framework, magento-2.1.3

I would like to override below file

**magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Captcha\Image.php**

Can we do with

**magento\app\code\zendframework1\library\Zend\Captcha\Image.php** ?

What will be the class extends?

Following http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

It's giving 90% answer.

**magento\app\code\Zend\Captcha\Image.php**

```
class Zend_Captcha_Image extends Zend_Captcha_Word
{
    protected function _generateImage($id, $word)
    {
    }
}
```

I want only this function. It gives abstract class error. If i only put this.

Can we override `composer.json` for this? Don't want to change in Magento Default

When u click on "Reload Captcha" it gives big DIV blank then it loads. It's not working as default works. Something still missing in override.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: you can check here, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/override-captcha-library-class-in-magento-2

Comment: @Rakesh I have updated question. Please guide if required to ask new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Magento_Captcha` module use `Zend_Captcha_Image` for generate of captcha images.

*Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel*:

```
class DefaultModel extends \Zend_Captcha_Image implements \Magento\Captcha\Model\CaptchaInterface
```

For extending image generation functionality, you can add you custom preference on `Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel`.

---

*di.xml*

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Captcha\MyCaptchaModel"/>
```

*MyCaptchaModel.php*:

```
/**
 * Class MyCaptchaModel.
 */
class MyCaptchaModel extends \Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _generateImage($id, $word)
    {
        //@TODO
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add plugin on `\Magento\Captcha\Model\CaptchaFactory::create()` and define your custom logic for creating instances of captcha models.