# Magento 2: Captcha overwrite fatal error on PHP 7

Tags: magento2, module, custom, magento-2.1.3, captcha

[Magento 2: How to override Zend library files function only?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155609/magento-2-how-to-override-zend-library-files-function-only)

I overwrite Captcha module on my WAMP PHP 5.X & it works fine.

On linux server which has PHP 7 gives below error

> Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Custom\Captcha\Model\CustomCaptcha::render(Custom\Captcha\Model\Zend_View_Interface
>   $view = NULL, $element = NULL) must be compatible with 
>                    Zend_Captcha_Adapter::render(Zend_View_Interface $view = NULL, $element = NULL) in
>   /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Custom/Captcha/Model/CustomCaptcha.php
>   on line 156 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html if you want to give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Zend_View_Interface` class does not imported in your scope.

You can use import in top of you file:

```
use Zend_Captcha_Image;
```

Or use full class name

```
public function render(\Zend_View_Interface $view = NULL, $element = NULL)
```